# Which approximation should I use?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I have a function $ k(x,y)$, and I want to approximate it for low values of x and y.

$k(x,y) = \dfrac{a^3-ax^2-x^3+a^2x+ay^2-xy^2}{a^3-ax^2+x^3-a^2x+ay^2+xy^2}$

With $ a>>x, a>>y $

Neglecting all higher powers gives:

$k(x,y) \approx \dfrac{a+x}{a-x}$

However, using a Taylor series in first order gives:

$k(x,y) \approx 1+\dfrac{2x}a$

Which one gives a more accurate result overall?

*Edited last line for clarification.

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: Which one is more accurate?

Comment: More accurate ... in what sense?

Comment: I was under the impression that one was always better than the other. At least you helped me get rid of that idea. I filled in some typical values, and plotted the result, in my case the first approximation is overall closer to the original. I'll close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor approximation $T_1(x, y) = 1 + \frac{2x}{a}$ satisfies
$$k(x, y) - T_1(x, y) = \frac{2 x^2}{a^2} + O((x, y)^3),$$ but
$$k(x, y) - \frac{a + x}{a - x} = O((x, y)^3) ,$$ so the latter approximation is better for small $x, y$.